# Library to verify GTINs of various lengths

Tags: python, object-oriented, validation, comparative-review

I'm writing a library to verify [GTINs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Trade_Item_Number) (GTIN-8, GTIN-12, GTIN-13, GTIN-14) and calculate their check digits. The calculation of the check digits don't differ from type to type, so I can use the same code for all types of GTINs.

My question: Should I use separate classes for each type of GTIN or should I store the length into an instance attribute?

I have listed two options (simplified):

### Option #1

```
import re

class GTIN:
    def __init__(self, gtin):
        self.gtin = self.parse(gtin)

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, gtin):
        parsed_gtin = cls.sanitize(gtin)
        if not cls.check_format(parsed_gtin)
            return None
        return parsed_gtin

    @classmethod
    def sanitize(cls, gtin):
        return re.sub(r'[\s\-]+', '', gtin)

    @classmethod
    def check_format(cls, gtin):
        if re.match(cls.FORMAT, gtin):
            return True
        return False

class GTIN8(GTIN):
    FORMAT = r'^[0-9]{7}[0-9?]{1}$'

class GTIN12(GTIN):
    FORMAT = r'^[0-9]{11}[0-9?]{1}$'
```

The given GTIN string can contain a `?` if the check digit should be calculated.

### Option #2

```
import re

class GTIN:
    ALLOWED_LENGTHS = [8, 12, 13, 14]

    def __init__(self, gtin):
        self.gtin = self.parse(gtin)

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, gtin):
        parsed_gtin = cls.sanitize(gtin)
        if not cls.check_format(parsed_gtin)
            return None
        return parsed_gtin

    @classmethod
    def sanitize(cls, gtin):
        return re.sub(r'[\s\-]+', '', gtin)

    @classmethod
    def check_format(cls, gtin):
        if len(gtin) in cls.ALLOWED_LENGTHS:
            self.length = len(gtin)
        else:
            return False

        format = r'^[0-9]{{{}}}[0-9?]{{1}}$'.format(self.length - 1)
        if re.match(format, gtin):
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: Why use a class at all?

Comment: Could you include the checksumming code as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume the variety of GTIN's are a bounded set.  If so, I see no use
in the inheritance.  Go with Option #2. And on that option I would recommend a
few changes

**Pre-build your formats into a `dict` based on length:**

This pre-builds and compiles the format regex's

```
formats = {l: re.compile(r'^[0-9]{{{}}}[0-9?]{{1}}$'.format(l - 1))
           for l in (8, 12, 13, 14)}
```

**Add a `__str__` method for easier debugging:**

This makes it easier to see what is going on in the debugger.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.gtin if self.gtin is not None else 'invalid'
```

**If you have an early return, put it in the if, not else:**

I would generally code something like this:

```
if len(gtin) in cls.ALLOWED_LENGTHS:
    self.length = len(gtin)
else:
    return False
```

as this:

```
if len(gtin) not in cls.formats:
    return False
....
```

**Define a `__len__` method if needed:**

I removed the `self.length` as it was not used internally, and a better way to publish the length is with a `__len__`.

```
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.gtin) if self.gtin is not None else 0
```

**Consume `bool` evaluations directly:**

If you need a bool and are performing a test to determine the bool state, you rarely need an if.  I redid this:

```
if re.match(format, gtin):
    return True
return False
```

as this (with some other changes also incorporated):

```
return cls.formats[len(gtin)].match(gtin) is not None
```

So there is no reason for the `if`, the result of the test can be returned (or assigned to a variable) directly.

**Entire Class:**

```
import re

class GTIN:
    formats = {l: re.compile(r'^[0-9]{{{}}}[0-9?]{{1}}$'.format(l - 1))
               for l in (8, 12, 13, 14)}

    def __init__(self, gtin):
        self.gtin = self.parse(gtin)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.gtin if self.gtin is not None else 'invalid'

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.gtin) if self.gtin is not None else 0

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, gtin):
        parsed_gtin = cls.sanitize(gtin)
        if not cls.check_format(parsed_gtin):
            return None
        return parsed_gtin

    @classmethod
    def sanitize(cls, gtin):
        return re.sub(r'[\s\-]+', '', gtin)

    @classmethod
    def check_format(cls, gtin):
        if len(gtin) not in cls.formats:
            return False
        return cls.formats[len(gtin)].match(gtin) is not None
```